# Arangodb Tarball distribution

Tags: centos, tar, arangodb

Is there a tarball distribution for arangoDB , to use on centos 7 ?

can I use  the github 3.1 tarball distibution? as an installation ?

any response is appreciated thank you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the "Github icon" download button in arangodb.com's download area will take you to the source files (https://www.arangodb.com/download-major/source/).
You should be able to compile these on your Centos installation.

You can of course also do a `git clone git://github.com/arangodb/arangodb.git`, check out the branch or tag that you need and compile from there.